# jquery: I'm trying to disable all buttons except the clicked button and not working

Tags: jquery, html

I want to disable all buttons except the clicked, I'm using jquery. Help please.
SOLVED:  removing :input inside '.not()'.

HTML

```
<div id="buttongroup">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butDes" class="butFiltro" value="Descripción" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butMaq" class="butFiltro" value="Máquina" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butDen" class="butFiltro" value="Denominación" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butFecEd" class="butFiltro" value="Fecha edición" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butFecCie" class="butFiltro" value="Fecha cierre" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butOpe" class="butFiltro" value="Operario" />
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="button" id="butNue" class="butFiltro" value="Nuevo" />
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
//$('.butFiltro').click(function(){

    var getValueButton = this.id;
    alert(getValueButton);
    $(':input').not('#'+getValueButton).attr('disabled', true);

});
```

Answer (score 6):

Change `var getValueButton = $(this).id;` to `var getValueButton = this.id`

Also use `.prop` instead of `attr`,

```
var $inputBtns = $('input[type=button]');

$inputBtns.click(function(){
    var getValueButton = this.id;
    $inputBtns.not('#'+getValueButton).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `this` and [.prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) is the right way to set the disabled property since jQuery 1.6+

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function(){
    $('input[type=button]').not(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
```

Comment: If you are doing `not(this)` when disabling buttons you dont need to remove it for `this` after. Also handler won't be triggered on disabled button.

Answer (score 2):

```
$('input[type=button]').click(function () {
    var getValueButton = this.id;  // $(this).id; is not correct
    $(':input').not('#' + getValueButton).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGdgW/)

**UPDATE**

Here's much simpler way:

```
var $inputs = $('input[type=button]');
$inputs.click(function () {
    $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGdgW/3/)

Comment: you already have your DOM element in `this`, no need to run selectors on document again.

Comment: I want same functionality on clicking 3 buttons all other should be disabled. How can I achieve so?